# Comparing dates without time

Tags: date, powershell, comparison

I have the following code that compares two dates. Is it possible to ignore the time that comes with `$ExpirationDate` and `$EndDate`?

```
if(((get-date $ExpirationDate).Date -gt (get-date $EndDate).Date) -And $userAccountControl -eq "512")
```

Comment: Your code already does ignore the time (that's what the `Date` property is for).

Comment: Yep the `.Date` sets the time to midnight.

Comment: Although it doesn't really matter. If the first `Date` itself is *greater than* the second, the entire `DateTime` (including the time of day) would also always be greater. Should you be using `-ge` (*greater than or equal to*) perhaps? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the type and value of `$ExpirationDate` and `$EndDate`?

Comment: I am trying to update a sharepoint list where $ExpirationDate is greater than $EndDate. $EndDate is a sharePoint field (aka column). I may have found a solution. I will update the post once I try the new solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `elseif` for AD account status 544 and that fixed the issue.

```
elseif(((get-date $ExpirationDate).Date -gt (get-date $EndDate).Date) -And $userAccountControl -eq "544")
```

Comment: So that means your question had nothing to do with datetime and your issue was with the logic of your conditions?